# C Program will not stop encountering EOF or -1

Tags: c

I am new beginner in C programming language.

Program will not stop from for or while loop if input is `EOF` or -1.

The program is like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double nc;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc) {
        printf("%.0f\n", nc);
    }
}
```

From my understanding, if I input `EOF` or -1 in terminate then the for loop will be stopped, as -1 or `EOF` makes the condition being false.

One more question regarding the same example: if I will not use nesting loop code as followings:

```
for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
    ;
printf("%.0f", nc);
```

No any error or alert, but it seems function `printf` does not work as expected. It just output what I input.

Comment: Quite strange to use a `double` as an incrementing counter, floating-point variables are not well suited for that role. How do you input `EOF`? You're not supposed to *type* the word, instead you must use some system-dependent way (in Linux, try `Ctrl+D`, in Windows it's `Ctrl+Z`).

Comment: Use int as counter, not double. getch() returns int, -1 or EOF entered in terminal isn't indicatinh end of file. Use ctrl+D in Linux or ctrl+Z in Windows

Comment: @Harveybegood: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey check mark below its score.

Answer (score 4):

Your program will stop at end of file, which is what `EOF` signifies.

To enter an end of file from the terminal, type <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on unix or Mac/OS and <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> on Windows systems.

<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> is obtained by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>D</kbd> while the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is held down.

Note that a `double` variable is not appropriate for a simple counter, you should favor the `int` type for this.

Note also that input is not received one character at a time by the program: it may be buffered on a line basis when reading from the terminal and on a block basis when reading from a file. A posted, your program will read a line of input from the terminal and as multiples lines of output at once, one for each character typed, including the newline.

Comment: Thank you, Chqrlie (charlie? sorry), even though i use int as a counter then the following program does not work as expected                         
 `for (nc =0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)                                                                                                      
           ;                                                                                                            
    printf("%d\n",nc); `

Comment: Thank you, Chqrlie (charlie? sorry),  I have one more question. below two snippet of codes work as same effectiveness? i think so. but the second will not output number as expected.              
 `int main()
{
        int nc;
        for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        {
                printf("%d",nc);
        }

}
`   `int main()
{
        int nc;
        for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;       
                printf("%d",nc);


}
   `

Comment: @Harveybegood: the first program outputs a number for each character typed at the terminal until end of file, while the second program only outputs the total number of characters types before the end of file. The `;` after the `(nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)` loop clauses is the single empty statement run for every iteration of the loop. It works the same as is you had written an empty block `{ }`.

Answer (score 2):

`EOF` is not something that you can input, rather a state the the file descriptor can be in.

To achieve this state on the console you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> if you're running a unix-like system.

---

Alternatively if you were to run your application by feeding in a file, you'd see that your application will stop once it has read to the end of the file.

```sh
./my_app < some_file.txt
```

---

Additionally, I would advise you to use an integer type to count loop iterations, for example `int`, or `size_t`. Floating point types are not well suited to this.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood...

If you enter EOF or -1 in console, you will get these as strings: `"EOF", "-1"`. If you read them character by character, you will get the sequences `'E', 'O', 'F'` and `'-', '1'` (numerical values, ASCII/UTF-8 provided: 69, 79, 70 and 45, 49 respectively), but never the numerical value of EOF(-1).

How to actually enter EOF: see chqrlie's answer, who has been faster than me...